# How to generate a tsconfig.json that matches package.json + tsc command?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, npm, webstorm

I'm using [TodoMvc Typescript-Angular](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/master/examples/typescript-angular) as blueprint for my AngularJS application. It is all good and works fine. Basically I can:

1. Install or update all dependencies with that `package.json` doing `npm install` or `npm update`.
2. Compile the ts code under js doing `npm run compile` which is configured to be `tsc --sourcemap --out js/Application.js js/_all.ts`.

I'm also working with WebStorm and would like to get the tsconfig.json equivalent to the command before ... how can I do that?

Doing `tsc --init` I get a new generic `tsconfig.json` generated but it is not the equivalent to the command `tsc --sourcemap --out js/Application.js js/_all.ts` ... is there a way to generate it according to a package.json setup? also taking into account the TS version there etc?

Comment: Is it a requirement of your question to generate the `tsconfig.json` file automatically without any further manual customization?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin no, writing an equivalent one is also perfect! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following config should work:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outFile": "js/Application.js"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "include": ["js/_all.ts"]
}
```

Comment: thanks! is it generating a single big `Application.js`? can it be added also how to generate the same output as in the OP?

Comment: yes, it's generating a single `Application.js` - just as when you run `tsc --out js/Application.js`